# Where is the APU in the case of an S-duct (like the L-1011)?

Tags: aircraft-design, apu, lockheed-tristar

[This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14864/why-is-the-nacelle-outlet-of-the-tail-engine-of-the-l-1011-tristar-lower-than-th?rq=1) asks about the S-duct of the L-1011 Tristar. [Fooot's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/14867/4197) shows a cut-out of the L-1011. Looking at this cut-out, I'm wondering:

**If the engine is at the 'normal' location of the APU, where did the designers of the L-1011 put the APU?**

I did a search, and found [this site](https://sites.google.com/site/thel1011projectwiki/aircraft-systems/auxiliary-power-unit-apu) which mentions

> The APU is located in a compartment in the aft fuselage.

[Another site](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/72027) mentions

> Its still in the "tail". Its mounted below the #2 engine. Just forward of the tail skid.

But I don't see how you could fit the APU in the small available space.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]
([Source](http://aircraft.wikia.com/wiki/Lockheed_L-1011_Tristar?file=Cutaway.jpg) via aircraft.wikia.com)

APU is number 134 on the cutaway, which you can find near root of left stabilator leading edge. It is ahead of the engine, below the intake duct, on the left side.

[image]
By Reedy (Own work) [[CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)], [via Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3ALockheed_L-1011_TriStar_N700TS%2C_National_Airline_History_Museum%2C_Kansas_2013-03-16_(105).jpg)

Its exhaust is on the right side close to the stabilator's leading edge.

Answer (score 8):

The APU on the B727 was placed inside the main gear wheel well.

[image]

<sup>[image source](http://www.britmodeller.com/forums/index.php?/topic/234920495-boeing-727/)</sup>

It drew air from inside the wheel well, so it was only for use on the ground. The exhaust was on the top of the right wing close to the fuselage.

[image]

<sup>[image source](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=775445)</sup>

Comment: And man is it loud. SOURCE: worked on them for 20 years.

Comment: @SportsRacer Yes they were. Used to work at the FedEx hub back when the fleet was mostly 727's. The head cans we wore were not enough working at the belly cargo doors.

Comment: Does this mean the APU  in the 727 couldn't be used to provide emergency power in air?

Comment: @TomMcW: Did they not have ground power in Memphis?

Comment: Some places on the ramp probably did. When I was there a large portion of the 727's were on remote stands.

Comment: @zymhan Just saw your question. The APU on a 727 cannot be operated in flight. Ground use only.